# How to fill a zeros matrix with an extremely low density of ones

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a 3D matrix of zeros of size (850,850,850) and I would like to insert ones in this matrix in an homogeneous way with an extremely low density=8*10^-7.
I tried to use the random.sparse (which worked for higher density) but it doesn't work, I think the density is too low and it's approximated to zero, in fact there are no ones where indeed there should be 50 ones.
here it's the code for better understanding:

```
import numpy as np
import random

space=np.zeros(shape=(850,850,850))
den=50/(850*850*850)
for k in range (0,850): 
   rdm_space=sparse.random(850, 850, density=den, data_rvs=np.ones)
   rdm_space=rdm_space.toarray()                                                                 
   space[:][:][k] = vac_space
```

Does someone have any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why do you need sparse sampling if you end up with NumPy array

Just sample indices and set values to 1

Along the lines

```
import numpy as np

N = 850*850*850
o = 50
space=np.zeros(N, dtype=np.int32)

idx = np.random.choice(N, size=o, replace=False) # sampled indices

space[idx]=1 # set values at idx to one

# quick check
q = space[space>0]
print(len(q))

# make final properly shaped array
np.reshape(space, newshape=(850,850,850))
```